# How to get DataTable in vb.net using sql Connection

Tags: vb.net, sqlconnection

```
Dim oConnString As String
Dim strQuery As String
Dim myConn As SqlConnection
Dim myCmd As SqlCommand
Dim myReader As SqlDataReader
Dim results As String

oConnString = "Data Source=" + strServerName + "; Database='" + strDatabaseName + "';Integrated Security=true"

Dim oConnection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(oConnString)
strQuery = "SELECT * from Usertable"

myCmd = oConnection.CreateCommand
myCmd.CommandText = strQuery
oConnection.Open()

myReader = myCmd.ExecuteReader()

'Some codes here'

myReader.Close()
myConn.Close()
```

'===============================================================================================
Any idea on this error?
I encountered an error during processing this line "myReader = myCmd.ExecuteReader()"
Error:
"Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in System.Data.dll
Additional information: Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding."

i am expecting to read all the column in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the command timeout

```
myCmd.CommandTimeout = 5*60 '5 min
```

To get a DataTable from the reader:

```
Dim myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
Dim dataTable = New DataTable()
dataTable.Load(myReader)
```